# nginx php5-fpm failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, nginx, php

**QUESTION: What am I missing or doing wrong?**

I'm trying to migrate fully functional Zend Framework application from Apache2 with mod_php5 to nginx with php5-fpm. I get this kind of errors:

`2012/06/27 12:08:04 [error] 1986#0: *1 open() "/var/www/public/sales/live-trials-json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: *.*.*.*, server: www.mydomain.com, request: "POST /sales/live-trials-json HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mydomain.com", referrer: "https://www.mydomain.com/sales/live-trials"`

Here are my configuration files:

a) /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 default ssl;

  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/public;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

  index index.php index.phtml index.html;

  location = /(favicon.ico|robots.txt) {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location ~* ^.+.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|xml) {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

b) /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;
fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https;
# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```

c) /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 6
chdir = /
```

d) ls -al /var/www

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 27 10:52 application
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 27 10:52 library
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 27 12:05 public
```

e) nginx -V

```
nginx version: nginx/1.1.19
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments:
  --prefix=/etc/nginx
  --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log
  --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body
  --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi
  --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
  --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy
  --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi
  --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi
  --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock
  --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid
  --with-debug
  --with-http_addition_module
  --with-http_dav_module
  --with-http_geoip_module
  --with-http_gzip_static_module
  --with-http_image_filter_module
  --with-http_realip_module
  --with-http_stub_status_module
  --with-http_ssl_module
  --with-http_sub_module
  --with-http_xslt_module
  --with-ipv6
  --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl
  --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl
  --with-mail
  --with-mail_ssl_module
  --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam
  --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-echo
  --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
  --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
```

f) php -v (this is cli version, but I swear I am running nginx with fpm:)

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr 11 2012 17:25:33) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: I have also changed in fastcgi_params as people complained in below article and still nothing: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,214780,215113

Comment: What's the output from `ls -l /var/www/public/sales/live-trials-json`?

Comment: It doesn't exist, of course. Zend Framework rewrites the rules and runs corresponding controller and action. Check this out: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html

Comment: Ah, good, then you've got a good place to start -- it _tried_ to access that file, so perhaps the rewriting is broken.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense, since it's working for all HTTP GET and not working for any HTTP POST. Judging from this point of view, I think rewrite is fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, after long and exhausting struggles, I've managed to figure out this madness. So, I've started everything from scratch and here is what I've learned:

**Entire weirdness is somewhere in `location ~* ... { ... }`, so whoever have better experience, please explain why :-) Meanwhile I'll manage assets and caching on application layer.**

My functional configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 default ssl;

  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/public;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

  index index.php index.phtml index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Thanks for trying, especially @sarnold and @sergei-lomakov!

Comment: this worked for me, except I had to change one line: comment out "include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;" and add "include fastcgi.conf;"

Answer (score 9):

Your nginx configuration is little wrong.

Because agree with your rules, nginx tries to access /var/www/public/sales/live-trials-json
which doesn't exist.

Because I don't know which endpoints your application use, I suggest you to make two nginx locations. First , for all static files (with regexp) create this location:

```
location ~* ^.+.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|xml) {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
  }
```

All another queries should be proxied to apache:

```
  location / {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
```

Make little change with this rule:

```
  location ~* ^/(favicon.ico|robots.txt)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }
```

Of course, you can leave ".ht settings" untouched:

```
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
```

So, Final config will be:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 default ssl;

  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/public;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

  index index.php index.phtml index.html;

  location ~* ^/(favicon.ico|robots.txt)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location ~* ^.+.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|xml) {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
# I'm not sure that this setting is needed:
#        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }


}
```

Comment: Nope, this is not the right answer. I've literally copy pasted your configuration file and it's still not working, throwing same errors.

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, your problem is with

```
location ~* ^.+.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|xml) {
  access_log off;
  expires 30d;
}
```

This matches your POST uri of /sales/live-trials-json because it hasn't been anchored to the end of the uri path, and . matches any character.  This means that '-js' matches.  To fix this, you just need to add a \ (to match a literal '.') and a $ (to anchor the match at the end of the uri path):

```
location ~* \.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|xml)$ {
  access_log off;
  expires 30d;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it's only 50% of the problem. The other 50% of the problem was pointed out by previous responder, Sergei Lomakov... So I don't know how to divide the bounty points between you guys! I guess it's fair to give them to Sergei, since he guided to the right answers :)